# Custom Key Value fields in a content type

Tags: 6, entities

I am searching for functionality similar to the [Double Field](http://drupal.org/project/double_field) module only for Drupal 6.

Does anyone know of a suitable module or if not, could you outline an approach to creating this functionality?

Thanks, apologies if this is poorly explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise I'm answering my own question here but I've done some digging and come across the [TableField](http://drupal.org/project/tablefield) module.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

It appears to do something along the lines of DoubleField.